# How to apply RBF (Replace-by-Fee)

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, replace-by-fee

I got a stuck transaction and would like to clear this. I found many information about RBF (Replace-by-Fee) how it works etc. So i think this might be the best option to get my transaction going.

Unfortunately i couldnt find any information about how to apply this command to the existing unconfirmed and zero-fee transaction. Please advise.

THank you so much

Answer (score 3):

[RBF Tools by Peter Todd](https://github.com/petertodd/replace-by-fee-tools)

This page contains

> ..tools to test out replace-by-fee functionality. You'll need a local
>   node with the replace-by-fee patch.

E.g. 
To double spend `./double-spend.py <address> <amount>`

To just increase fee `./bump-fee.py <txid>` etc.

Comment: but how to enable replace-by-fee in bitcoin-core?

Comment: It is not implemented yet.

Comment: "You'll need a local node with the replace-by-fee patch. A version applied to Bitcoin Core v0.11.0 is available at https://github.com/petertodd/bitcoin/tree/replace-by-fee-v0.11.0 "